DATE in DuckDB showing also time
I've been trying to create a table in DuckDB database for stock prices. Everything works ok except for date (which is EOD from yahoo finance): it should be 2024-01-02 but in DB its: 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000. What am I missing here? I even placed SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) but it didn't help either.
import yfinance as yf
import duckdb
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Download data
data = yf.download('AAPL', start='2024-01-01', rounding=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Set Date column as a date without the time component
data['Date'] = data['Date'].dt.date

# Rename the 'Adj Close' column to 'Adj_Close'
data.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'Adj_Close'}, inplace=True)

# Database connection path for DuckDB
db_path = "SPY.duckdb"
conn = duckdb.connect(db_path)
symbol = "SPY"

# Create table
create_table_query = f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {symbol} (
            Date DATE UNIQUE,
            Open FLOAT,
            High FLOAT,
            Low FLOAT,
            Close FLOAT,
            Adj_Close FLOAT,
            Volume BIGINT
        );
        """
conn.execute(create_table_query)

# Insert data into DuckDB with explicit casting of Date column
conn.execute(f"INSERT INTO {symbol} SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE), Open, High, Low, Close, Adj_Close, Volume FROM data")


How to get rid of time stamp in DB?

Question: Why does the time component pose a problem for you?  If you don't need it, then ignore it.

Because if we are talking about whole universe of US stocks (ca 5000 stocks) that gives a lot of GB of unnecessary storage

Your code gives me column not found errors as data.columns is a MultiIndex - so all the names end up as stringified tuples in DuckDB. Inspecting duckdb.sql("from data") shows me a column named ('Date', '') of type date - without any explicit CAST needed.

Let's try this implementation.
Remove (backup) your previous SPY.duckdb file
import yfinance as yf
import duckdb
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)

data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2024-01-01", rounding=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

data["Date"] = data["Date"].dt.date

data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "Adj_Close"}, inplace=True)

if isinstance(data.columns, pd.MultiIndex) and data.columns.nlevels > 1:
    data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(1)

db_path = "SPY.duckdb"
conn = duckdb.connect(db_path)
symbol = "SPY"


# Create table
create_table_query = f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {symbol} (
            Date DATE UNIQUE,
            Open FLOAT,
            High FLOAT,
            Low FLOAT,
            Close FLOAT,
            Adj_Close FLOAT,
            Volume BIGINT
        );
        """
conn.execute(create_table_query)

data.to_sql(symbol, conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)


row_data_from_db = conn.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {symbol} limit 1").fetchall()

print(row_data_from_db)

it gives us
[(datetime.date(2024, 1, 2), 184.94000244140625, 185.63999938964844, 188.44000244140625, 183.88999938964844, 187.14999389648438, 82488700)]


